# PHPUnit ArgumentCountError

Tags: php, phpunit

I am relatively new to PHPUnit and I've been trying to do a simple testing to return true/ false upon a successful login. Below is my source code.

```
 <?php
 include 'user.php';

 class test extends PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
 {
   
    public function login($username, $password)
    {
        $user = new user(); 
        $login = $user-> login($username = 'username1', $password = '123456';
    
        if ($login)
        {
            return true; 
        }
    }  
   
    public function testTrue($username, $password)
    {
        
        if ($actual = (new login())-> login('username1', '123456'))
            
            $this->assertSame($expected = true, $actual);
        else
             
            $this->assertSame($expected = fail, $actual);
        
    }
} 
?>
```

The error I faced "ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function login::testpass()" and Im not sure why is it so and how can I troubleshoot this issue!

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
if ($actual = (new login())-> login('username1', '123456'))
```

use

```
if ($actual = ($this->login('username1', '123456'))
```